# Automatically iterate through td tags in a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement a timer function that would scroll through each td tag in a table and make it "selected".  This would happen automatically.  It could be overridden by clicking on the specific td tag and 'selecting' that one.  A play button would start the sequence.  A stop button would halt the sequence.

Here is the javascript code I have that makes the table (the id for each td is made up from a unique 'species id' number and a year, from 1966 to 2012).  It is in the body tag.

```
    <script>
    var year = 1966;
    var speciesNum = document.getElementById("selectboxEnglish").value
    document.write("<table id='yeartable' border='0'>");

    for (var r=0; r<5; r++)
    {
        document.write("<tr>");
        for (var d=0; d<=9; d++)
        {
            document.write("<td id="+speciesNum+"_"+year+">" + year + "</td>");
            year+=1;
            if (year == 2013){break};
        }
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Here is the current jquery function I have that uses mouseover event to select the specific td tag (it is in the head tag :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("td").addClass("unselected");

        $("td").mouseover(function () {
            $("td").removeClass("unselected");
            $("td").addClass("unselected");
            $(this).removeClass("unselected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var fileName = getFileName($(this).attr("id"));
            $("#imgYear").attr("src", fileName);
            $("#imgYear").attr("alt", fileName);
        });
    });
```

Please help.

Comment: Why are you doing this `$("td").removeClass("unselected");` and then `$("td").addClass("unselected");`? Also, can't you just have one class e.g. `.selected`, and if it's not present you assume it's unselected - makes more sense

Comment: You should really rename your question! I think you mean "iterate" instead of "scroll", am I right?

Comment: @Julian Yes!  Thank you I renamed the question.

Comment: @IanClark Those two lines are to make sure nothing is selected with the page loads.

Comment: @MattL, it still doesn't make sense to remove the `.unselected` class on all `td`s and then put them back, you'd just use `.addClass`

Comment: Also, if you're going to use the jQuery library, IMO it doesn't make much sense to not utilise it wherever you can. e.g. `var speciesNum = document.getElementById("selectboxEnglish").value` could just be `var speciesNum = $("#selectedboxEnglish").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this basic implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/b9XRc/4), though I'm not using an `.unselected` class, as I don't see why you need one (see my comment against your question). The solution is as follows (with extra commenting) (**Edit** - added stop and reset functionality, **Edit #2** - only one element is `.selected` at a time) :

**JavaScript**

```
// Establish a default queue (in your case, all your tds)
var originalQueue = queue = $("td"),
    selectionTimeout;

// Recursive function to highlight all elements
function highlight_all(elems) {
    // Remove selected class on all queue elements
    originalQueue.removeClass("selected");
    // Shift first element from list, and re-add selected class to it
    var next = elems.eq(0).addClass("selected");
    // Remove it from the queue
    queue = elems.slice(1);
    // If any more elements, set a timeout to repeat in 100ms
    if (queue.length) {
        selectionTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            highlight_all(queue)
        }, 100);
    }
}

// Start the selections based on current queue
$("#start").on("click", function () {
    highlight_all(queue);
});

// Clear the timeouts, stopping any more being selected
$("#stop").on("click", function () {
    clearTimeout(selectionTimeout);
});

// Clear the timeout, reset the queue to it's default state
// and remove selected classes
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    clearTimeout(selectionTimeout);
    originalQueue.removeClass("selected");
    queue = originalQueue;
});
```

Comment: I need the .unselected class because I only want one td to be selected at any one time.

Comment: I've updated it so that only one class has `.selected` at any given time, but I still don't understand the requirement for an `.unselected` class. If your cells have two states, unselected and selected, you only need one class to toggle between them.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I want.  How do I go about starting and stopping the process though?

Comment: How do you mean? Look at my `#start`, `#stop` and `#reset` events?